# Validation- prompting user again for input if input is wrong

Tags: python, validation, if-statement

Here is my [python](/questions/tagged/python) code:

```py
while exit:
    serialnumber = int(input("serial number of product :"))
    try:
        if len(str(serialnumber)) == 6:
            break
        else:
            print("serial number cant be used")

        serialnumber = int(serialnumber)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        print()
```

I have been trying to make a length check on the input so that it does not go over 6 characters.

I would also like my program to keep asking for input until it passes the check.

However, in my program, if the input fails the check then it will just display the serial number and it won't prompt the user again.

Comment: Instead of checking the length of a string, just check the number: `if serialnumber < 1000000:`

Comment: `serialnumber = int(serialnumber)` is unnecessary, it's already an `int`.

Comment: `== 6` should be `<= 6`. You're requiring that it be exactly 6 characters, not just that it doesn't go over 6 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `break` after the `if/else` statements, so the loop stops even after printing `serial number cant be used`. Get rid of that.

There's no need for the `exit` variable, which is never updated in the loop, just use `while True:` to make a loop that repeats until it executes `break`.

```
while True:
    serialnumber = int(input("serial number of product :"))
    try:
        if serialnumber < 1000000:
            break
        else :
            print("serial number cant be used")
    except ValueError :
        print("Invalid input")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`try`-`except`-`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to tidy-up you code. You should also check for negative inputs.

```
while True:
    try: 
        serialnumber = int(input("serial number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid input")
    else:
        if serialnumber >= 0 and serialnumber < 1_000_000:
            break
        print("serial number can't be used")
```